# Office.js Binding Management in Excel

Tags: office-js

Should I be doing any sort of release on my cell bindings that are made in my add-in?  Do the bindings persist beyond a session?  So, if a user closes the add-in by clicking the 'x' in the top right corner of the add-in and then reopens the add-in, will those previous bindings still exist and trigger their respective handlers?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bindings persist invisibly in a workbook. Closing the task pane does not remove them. However, when your task pane launches again, the Binding events won't trigger their handlers unless you first call `Binding.addHandlerAsync()` again (docs: https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/binding.addhandlerasync).

So whenever your add-in loads, you should check for existing bindings and add the appropriate event handlers to them.

When you no longer need a binding, you should remove it for performance optimization: call the Binding.delete() method (docs: https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/excel/binding#delete). If you still want to save the binding but you also want to stop receiving event notifications during a session, you can instead remove the handler with Binding.removeHandlerAsync() (docs: https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/binding.removehandlerasync)

-Michael (Program Manager for Office add-ins)

Comment: If  I don't care for those bindings to persist between sessions, do I need to release the bindings at the start of a new session to avoid overlapping bindings/conflicts and potential memory leaks/overloading of the memory?  Or is that something which will not occur, and I don't need to worry about it?

Comment: Yeah, there are some cleanup instructions. I'll update my answer above, hold on...

Comment: Updated, sorry - got sidetracked :)